(polyglossia breaks) Struggling to add Kanji and other japanese characters to a multilanguage book document
Using Texstudio on Miktex, I'm writing a poetry book in 5 languages. Among 4 european, also Japanese. I was starting out with pdflatex using babel for the german \glqq and \grqq. For the kanji I took a screenshot of the correct signs and photoshopped them into a black/white image and pasted them in the line in a box until it fits.
But I can't do that for every poem, it doesn't work in headlines of chapters. And I got one chapter headline with Kanji. Plus, if I need to change one kanji/hiragana, I am in trouble.
I used Ai to check on possible solutions (I know, don't trust it, sometimes it's doing weird things). I couldn't find anything helpful, okay I got the font type Noto_Sans_JP now, but not Noto_Sans_CJK_JP, I couldn't find it. I don't know if that does make a difference. If it does, please do let me know.
Either way, pdflatex -> switched to lualatex, hoped I could then replace babel with this ominous "polyglossia". My "polyglossia" is always crossed through and in a different color saying not found, but I installed it? My MikTex recognizes it clearly.  I also had to replace the babel \glqq and \grqq with "csquotes" which is also crossed through. I don't know if polyglossia is working or not, but it throws errors.
Because my lines sometimes contain multiple languages, it's just one huge mess now. My latin characters text seems fine but the kanji are from just space bars to empty boxes, instead of what they should be.
I tried to create a minimum example, this one is also having an error called "Key 'fontspec-opentype/Script' accepts only a fixed set of(LaTeX) choices." What does that mean? I just did what I thought would work. Here a screenshot. You can see how both key words are crossed out and pink, also notice the quotes working but not the Japanese symbols.
Code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Füge fontspec hinzu, um Schriftarten zu verwalten
\usepackage{polyglossia} % Verwende polyglossia für mehrsprachige Unterstützung

\usepackage{csquotes}

\setdefaultlanguage{english} % Setze die Standardsprache auf Englisch
\setotherlanguages{ngerman,french,spanish,japanese} % Füge Deutsch, Französisch und Japanisch hinzu

% Setze die Hauptschriftart auf die Standard-Schriftart
\newfontface\japanesefont[Script=Japanese]{Noto Sans JP} % Definiere die japanische Schriftart

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{ngerman}{german}


\begin{document}
    .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\ .\\
    „Dies ist ein Beispiel für deutsche Anführungszeichen.“
    ``Dies ist ein Beispiel für englische Anführungszeichen.''
    水僕の心 Suiboku no Kokoro...
    
\end{document}


According to Ecosia Ai, I might have issues with the font, so I opened word pad and put in that Kanji. It was rendered just fine in the font type "Noto Sans JP". 
I also checked the font type was the same. For the main font type, I didn't want to change it, so I didn't declare any. When I put the font type in there that I was told LaTex is using, all my text was gone so I removed that line entirely, instead. I also triple-checked whether LuaLaTeX was the active compiler. 
The main issue I thought would have was package incompatibilities but I assume none of those I left out remotely had to do with why the Kanji just won't get drawn. Image for comparison. Both documents fail. 
So, after all the issues I am facing, what is it I have overseen? I am not experienced with LaTeX at all, but I assume it must be possible to print both german, english, french, spanish and japanese text on the same page, is it not?
I hope somebody can help me fix this issue so I can continue working on my book. Was it wrong to switch from pdflatex using babel to lualatex using polyglossia? Are there alternatives that work with less issues? Thanks in advance.

If you switch the language you must tell that to polyglossia so that it can switch the font eg use \foreignlanguage. You can  use Japanese also with babel. And babel is able to do the font switch automatically based on the script.

The following works for me on a current miktex with lualatex (you must have the noto font installed as a system font)
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman,french,spanish,english,]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}
\babelfont[japanese]{rm}{Noto Sans JP}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\enquote{Dies ist ein Beispiel für englische Anführungszeichen.}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\enquote{Dies ist ein Beispiel für deutsche Anführungszeichen.}
    
\glqq Dies ist ein Beispiel für deutsche Anführungszeichen.\grqq
    
    
    水僕の心 Suiboku no Kokoro...
    
\end{document}



Thank you, this answer helped me fix my document. I hope you have a good day.
